# Qt automoc giving bizarre errors unless a GUI-specific include file is added

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5, moc

I'm using CMake's AUTOMOC via:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
```

I was factoring out a class from a working file that did:

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "workingstuff.h"
```

The factored-out class didn't have any GUI code, and really only used QObject and QString in its forward definition.  So I thought I'd pare down the includes for the broken-out file to just:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include "workingstuff.h"
```

Despite workingstuff being just fine elsewhere, it began having very random-seeming errors.  Not when building `newfile.cpp` or `newfile.h`, only when workingstuff was being built as an include from `moc_newfile.cpp`  The errors weren't at the top of the file on the first definition, but way in the middle...like:

```
#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE 0    // "expected unqualified-id before numeric constant"
#define TRUE (!0)
#endif
```

*(That's a puzzle because it's hard to imagine what it can be complaining about while processing a line after a preprocessor directive where it's just decided that thing doesn't exist... and sets it to zero.  :-/)*

Since this message is hindsight, I've already pointed to what the breaking difference was found to be: it would work by including `<QtWidgets>` (either as a replacement for `<QString>` and `<QObject>`, or in addition).  I tried some other includes to see if they would have the same magical effect: `<QThread>` and `<QTimer>` did not, while `<QMessageBox>` did.

"workingstuff.h" is basically just a plain C library that happens to be buildable as C++...no Qt dependency whatsoever.  Is there a requirement I don't know about automoc that you need to include some GUI-related file, or it will have strange errors while building the moc?

Comment: It's impossible to know what's going on as you don't post relevant code that reproduces the issue. The problems you have aren't "random": they are fully reproducible and have a trivial cause. You're including some code somewhere that pollutes the global namespace with macros that break other code, or your own headers are fundamentally broken somehow. Make sure you have include guards on all your headers!

Comment: @KubaOber "You're including some code somewhere that pollutes the global namespace with macros that break other code, or your own headers are fundamentally broken somehow." => Can you explain how I'd be able to get the error "expected unqualified-id before numeric constant" on `#define FALSE 0` after `#ifndef FALSE`?  What pollution of namespaces can I do to make that happen?  Yes, I can try and create a smaller repro case (will take time, as docs for automoc are slight I thought I might save some by asking).  Just don't see how including an extra Qt file would sort out "my problems".

Comment: There's some junk before that #define, in previously included headers.

Comment: @KubaOber I will try and create a smaller repro than what I have.  The problem is that I just don't understand how adding a QtGui file into the mix would "clear up" the problem.  It seems adding more includes would make it worse.  :-/  In any case, the cpp files themselves compile fine along with the header, it's only the moc-generated file that the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: The junk happens to be added when you have a wrong order of include files... An include file somewhere is defining *something* (nothing to do with FALSE/TRUE!) that messes up the syntax in (likely) some subsequent file to be included, so that the *next* file after that to be included becomes invalid (that's where the compiler error pops up).